# How to get the name and response data of the child sampler that is under transaction controller?

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I would like to save the samplers' name and response data to a file if they are failed. The samplers are under the transaction controller and Generate Parent Sample is selected. For example,  I have 3 samplers (Sampler A, Sampler B, Sampler C) under a transaction controller. If Sampler A and Sampler C are failed, The name of Sampler A and Sample C and their response data should be saved into a file.

```
 Transaction Controller (Generate Parent Sample is selected)
   Sampler A
   Sampler B
   Sampler C
```

I have tried the following code in a JSR223 Listener. But it only saved Sampler C into the file although both Sample A and Sample C were failed.

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    def file = new File("failures.txt")
    def sample = prev.getThreadName() + " || " + sampler.getName()

    file << sample << System.getProperty('line.separator')
    file << prev.getResponseDataAsString() << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

Comment: Running test in non-gui mode, if you have Transaction Controller and Generate Parent Sample is selected in the test plan, there is no way to get the error response data from the child requests. No one encountered this issue?